# Difference between 5 V supply and 5 V output

Tags: power-supply, pcb-design

I work in PCB assembly, and I understand the need to separate different power supplies, (ie limiting the incoming power to protect the components, then seperating that into the different voltage levels used in the operation of the board, in this case 5V, 3.3V, and 10V, then separating out digital and analog sources to assist with isolation) but I cannot understand why this board has 10V_OUT and 5V_OUT, but not 3.3V_OUT.

Below is the subcircuit between 10V and 10V_OUT. The one between 5V and 5V_OUT is identical except for the voltage of the diode above ground, which is 5.6V in that case.
[image: Subcircuit schematic]

Comment: Your Mosfet is shown with its Drain and Source pins wrongly swapped.

Comment: It's not clear what you are actually asking. Do you want to know how this circuit works?

Comment: @Audioguru That depends on if the intention of the MOSFET is to serve as reverse polarity protection or as a power-on switch.

Answer (score 1):

When the voltage goes above 10 V, some current flows through the Zener, which pulls the base of the PNP low, which pulls the gate of the MOSFET up, which disconnects the supply (if you swap the source/drain; the schematic shown is wrong). So this is an overvoltage protection circuit.

The inductor and capacitor filter out high-frequency noise.

Apparently, the designer of the circuit did not think this would be necessary for the 3.3 V supply.

Comment: The mosfet in the circuit is the wrong way around to disconnect the power supply

Comment: @Ferrybig Thanks!

Comment: @Ferrybig Not if the intention was to create a reverse polarity protection (I can't tell, seems overly complicated if that was the case). For reverse polarity protection you would use a PMOS with drain towards the input, then tie the gate to ground, so that in case ground becomes a positive voltage, the PMOS will shut and disconnect what is supposed to be V+ but which is now an accidental ground.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the (very limited) schematics you provided, I see 2 possible explanations for the 10V_out :

- either it is a real output of the PCB (ie to power some external PCB/component), in which case the circuit shown prevents the external component to back-power the PCB
- or it is an "internal" voltage rail : in this case, it prevents the capacitors of the "out" side to discharge into the "in" side if power is turned off (might be needed to allow some circuit on the out side to do some "turn off" procedure, using only the energy stored in the capacitors.

In both cases, the circuit is basically an "ideal" diode + filtering.

For the 3.3V, it seems that the designer don't needed this feature. Maybe because the 3.3V is generated from an existing rail (5V or 10V), or because there is no output connector using the 3.3V